# How to pass a file path as a String to DAO class to store in the database through Spring REST Controller

Tags: java, mysql, spring, rest

I want to pass a file path as a String to DAO Class through service Class to store in the mySQL database using REST Controller. I tried with some approach but it's not working. Any idea on this?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST, headers=("content-type=multipart/*"))
public @ResponseBody void handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

    String itr =  file.getOriginalFilename();

    fileMeta = new Document();
    try {
        fileMeta.setBytes(file.getBytes());

        FileCopyUtils.copy(file.getBytes(), new FileOutputStream("D:/temp/files/"+file.getOriginalFilename()));

    } catch (IOException e) {   
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav

Comment: @StanislavL, I want to get the file path after storing the file locally

Comment: The just use "D:/temp/files/"+file.getOriginalFilename() that's the file path

Comment: @StanislavL, How can I convert it to String?

Answer (score 0):

```
String filePath = String.format("D:%stemp%sfiles%s%s, File.separator, File.separator, File.separator, file.getOriginalFilename());
FileCopyUtils.copy(file.getBytes(), new FileOutputStream(filePath);
```

FileCopyUtils.copy will write this file bytes to "filePath", according to your request, the rest you need to do it storing this path to mysql db.